# Is it possible to destroy/clear viewModel

Tags: android, android-livedata

In my **activity#1** I create my viewModel like this:

```
val viewViewModelProvider = ViewModelProviders.of(this) 
bluetoothPageViewModel = viewViewModelProvider.get(BluetoothPageViewModel::class.java)
```

Nice it's work fine.
But I need when forward to another activity (**activity#2**) to destroy or clear all data in `bluetoothPageViewModel`.Because when I return (press back button) to **activity#1** I need all data in `bluetoothPageViewModel` to be in init values.

Is it possible.

Comment: These answers might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53653157/manually-clearing-an-android-viewmodel

Comment: `onActivityResult() -> myViewModel.initialisationFunction()` ?

Comment: @IvanWooll before start activity#2 I use this in activity#1:  viewModelStore.clear(). And now it's work fine